# Flutter Custom Switch is not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am using 2 Custom Switches in Flutter. I want that when the user turns on the first switch the 2nd one should automatically turn off. And when the user turns off the first one the 2nd one will automatically turn on. The same with 2nd one. This means that exactly one Switch is turned on. I am using Custom Switch and that's why I am facing an issue achieving this.
I am able to update the values of variables correctly as I described above but the toggle/switch does not change. It is because of my Custom Switch. How can I achieve this without removing my Custom switch? below is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';

import '../CustomWidgets/CustomSwitch.dart';

class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MenuScreen> createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  
  bool _Location = true;
  bool OutAndAbout = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    width: 80,
                    height: 60,
                      child: Center(child: GestureDetector(onTap: () => Get.back(), child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, size: 18, color: Colors.white,)))),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text("Skip/Share", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Color(0xffffffff))),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle
                        ),
                        child: Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.white, size: 16)
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 15),
                    Text("Fixed Location", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter", fontSize: 14.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Color(0xffffffff))),
                    Spacer(),
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.6,
                      child: Builder(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return CustomSwitch(
                          activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                          value: _Location,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _Location = value;
                              if(_Location){
                                OutAndAbout = false;
                                print("Out & About is $OutAndAbout");
                              }
                              else{
                                OutAndAbout = true;
                                print("Out & About is $OutAndAbout");
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Image.asset("assets/images/OutAndAboutIcon.png", width: 20, height: 20,))
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 15),
                    Text("Out & About", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter", fontSize: 14.5, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Color(0xffffffff))),
                    Spacer(),
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.6,
                      child: Builder(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return CustomSwitch(
                            activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                            value: OutAndAbout,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                OutAndAbout = value;
                                if(OutAndAbout){
                                  _Location = false;
                                  print("Location is $_Location");
                                }
                                else{
                                  _Location = true;
                                  print("Location is $_Location");
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And below is the code for the Custom Switch

```
library custom_switch;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final String activeText;
  final String inactiveText;
  final Color activeTextColor;
  final Color inactiveTextColor;

  const CustomSwitch(
      {
        required this.value,
        required this.onChanged,
        required this.activeColor,
        this.inactiveColor = Colors.grey,
        this.activeText = '',
        this.inactiveText = '',
        this.activeTextColor = Colors.white70,
        this.inactiveTextColor = Colors.white70});

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation _circleAnimation;
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 60));
    _circleAnimation = AlignmentTween(
        begin: widget.value ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: widget.value ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
              _animationController.reverse();
            } else {
              _animationController.forward();
            }
            widget.value == false
                ? widget.onChanged(true)
                : widget.onChanged(false);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 70.0,
            height: 35.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              // Switch on & off color and gradient.
              color: _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
                  ? Color(0xffD4D4D4)
                  : null,


              gradient: _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerRight ? LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  Color(0xffFF5A5A),
                  Color(0x505AB0FF),
                ],
              ) : null,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 4.0, left: 4.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerRight
                      ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34.0, right: 0),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.activeText,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.activeTextColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  )
                      : Container(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: _circleAnimation.value,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25.0,
                      height: 25.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
                      ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 34.0),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.inactiveText,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: widget.inactiveTextColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you are printing the `boolean`  objects - _Location  and OutAndAbout , Are values printing correctly? I have also posted using another approach, try that.

Answer (score 0):

It Should work, but Try this:

- In the `onChanged` callback of the `first switch`, update the value of the second switch accordingly and call setState to trigger a rebuild of the UI.

  ```
  onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
        _location = value;
        _outAndAbout = !value;
      });
  },
  ```
- In the `onChanged` callback of the `second switch`, update the value of the first switch accordingly and call setState to trigger a rebuild of the UI.

  ```
  onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
         _outAndAbout = value;
         _location = !value;
     });
  },
  ```